# Ubuntu Remmina "Protocol plugin RDP is not installed" Error, RDP missing

Tags: protocols, remote-desktop, rdp

Ubuntu 18.04:
It looks like the Remmina Remote Desktop app was updated today and I lost the RDP protocol in the process. VNC, SSH and SPICE are still available but no RDP.

I tried rebooting, uninstalling and reinstalling using:

```
sudo killall remmina
sudo apt-get purge remmina* -y
rm -Rf /home/`whoami`/.remmina/remmina.pref

sudo apt-get install remmina* -y
```

This combo'd with a reboot before and after but still no RDP.

I also noticed that the Ubuntu Software (Gnome Software) has 2 Remmina apps listed.

Answer (score 1):

I found a link (the fix) on Remmina website by accident. 
The normal install instructions on their site also did not work but then I looked at compiling from source.

https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Compilation/Compile-on-Ubuntu-18.04

I added to the "purge" section of the remove command above and this worked:

```
sudo killall remmina
sudo apt purge "remmina*" "libfreerdp*" "libwinpr*" "freerdp*"
rm -Rf /home/`whoami`/.remmina/remmina.pref
```

Reboot and then install using the "Ubuntu Software", choose the one with the mostly Blue icon.

It looks like the FreeRDP libraries may have been the issue for me.